How to print messages to stdout while using the -mwindows flag, portably?
I'm trying to write an SDL2 program in C. It takes input from argv and then creates a graphical window based on the flags/values passed. But I'm running into issues when linking with -mwindows and wanting to print a help message to stdout.
I would like the program to do the following

print a help message to stdout when the --help flag is passed from terminal/cmd.
create only the SDL window (no secondary terminal instance) when the binary is run from File Manager or Start Menu.

Is there a way to achieve both of them goals and keep the program portable?
I have tested linking with -mwindows and -mconsole, which each achieve one goal but not the other. I assume there's a way to achieve this via the Win32API but I'd like this to be portable so that's not ideal.
It seems both Firefox and SublimeText suffer from the same issue, where stdout is only logged when ran from an msys2 terminal (but not cmd). So I assume it isn't reasonably doable, however, on the off chance it is, it'd be real nice to have.
other quick note: I'd played around with splitting the program across 2 binaries, linking one with -mconsole and the other with -mwindows. Having the one act as a wrapper handling argument errors and messages and then have the wrapper execute the second binary which houses the core functionality. However, this feels sloppy and as implemented was using system() which is not portable, not secure, and very scary, so obviously this "solution" is not ideal either.

The duplicate questions for C++ also apply to C, too.
